# iOS Build app extension base on existing app. How to avoid code duplication?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios-app-extension, code-duplication

I have an iOS app that add Sound FX to videos. Now I want to build app extension target to support stocked Photo App. However, I have to duplicate almost every codes from the iOS app. And my solution that I have so far is to put common functions in a shared files and use it for both targets, because some codes in the app linked to AppDelegate and I can't use it in App Extension. Is there any better way to avoid code duplication in this case?

One more question: most extensions that I saw on AppStore only have 1 screen, is there any rules for this?

In my app, I have to let users to choose sounds from folder & library, and it requires navigation controller. But Navigation Controller is not usable in App Extension, should I build my own Navigaion Controller or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you don't need to target iOS 7 or earlier, you can put the common classes into a shared framework and load that framework from both targets.  This avoids having two instances of the code on disk.

As an added bonus, because of the way the OS handles shared library loading, all of the actual code pages get shared between the app and the extension, so you aren't wasting RAM, either.

Comment: Most of my classes are View Controller, and in the classes I reference to App Delegate which is not usable in App Extension

Comment: One solution is to add a layer of abstraction.  For example, you might create a singleton class that you store the interesting data in, instead of storing it in the app delegate, or you might create two classes with the same name—one in the app, where calling the method does something in the app delegate, and another in the extension whose methods do something different.

Comment: Another approach, if you don't actually need some of the functionality in the extension, would be to weak link against the app delegate class, and then check to see if the class itself is nil, and if it is, you're running in the extension, and you skip the behavior in question.

Comment: But the most common approach is to include only the portions that are truly shared in that shared framework, and add the remaining methods (stuff that's dependent on the app delegate) using categories (or extensions in Swift).

Comment: Would you please explain how to do this: "would be to weak link against the app delegate class, and then check to see if the class itself is nil,"

Comment: Read this Apple Doc: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/WeakLinking.html

Comment: Thanks. Let me check it. Another question: I use MixPanel analytic framework (cocoa pod), and it referenced App Delegate in their code, what should I do to make it work in App Extension?

Comment: You would have to also change its code to use some other class in the absence of the app delegate.